# How to make same width for 5 button horizontally in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've designed those 5 button in my storyboard based on iPhone6. Now problem is my client told me to make their app can be workable in iPhone5 onwards. Current those 5 buttons in iPhone5 cannot be displayed proportionally as same width. That's why my question is please let me know how to make same width for 5 button horizontally in xcode?

Comment: What's the minimum version of iOS your client wants you to support?

Comment: Are you using autolayout? If so you can set them to have equal widths with autolayout.

Comment: iOs9 version is their minimum version.

Comment: Just put 5 buttons in a `UIStackView` and set them to equal widths horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Add 5 `UIButton`s to yourViewController.
2. Highlight buttons
3. Click "Stack" icon at the bottom of the storyboard window.
4. On the `UIStackView's` attribute inspector, make sure it's "horizontal", distribution is set to "Fill Equally", and adjust the spacing to whatever you want.
5. Pin the `UIStackView` to left/right, top/bottom.

It should look something like this when you're done:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using a stackView works great but for those whose target is below iOS 9, you can do it very simply with autolayout. Just select all 5 labels and use the "pin" icon on the bottom of the storyboard to check "equal width".

Answer (score 0):

As already said in the comments you can create an Horizontal Stack View. Then add the 5 buttons to the Stack View.

[image]

Finally you can select the spacing by selecting the Stack View and, in the Attribute Inspector, increasing the `Spacing` field.

Comment: @Adrian: Yeas, your answer did appear while I was adding the image :D